# PHP Работа с json

Tags: php, json, yii2

Вообщем с помощью расширения динамические формы и мультиполя для yii2, храню в mysql наборы данных в json полях, написал для сайта api вывожу всю эту вещь форматирую массив, и пытаюсь отдать, но у меня есть эта самая json строка которая выглядит так:

```
[
    {
        "hour": "14", 
        "minutes": [
            {"minute": "00", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "10", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "20", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "30", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "40", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "50", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}
        ], 
        "price_stud": "1", 
        "price_adults": "1", 
        "tickets_left": "6", 
        "count_tickets": "6", 
        "price_children": "1"
    }, {
        "hour": "15", 
        "minutes": [
            {"minute": "00", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "10", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "20", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "30", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "40", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}, 
            {"minute": "50", "count_ticket": 1, "count_ticket_left": 1}
        ], 
        "price_stud": "1", 
        "price_adults": "1", 
        "tickets_left": "6", 
        "count_tickets": "6", 
        "price_children": "1"
    }
]
```

Вообщем, что может быть проще, но я почему-то застрял на этому моменте, а пытаюсь я полчить до ступ к этому чуду вот так:

```
foreach ($scheduleTickets as $ticket) {
    $new_date_ticket = new DateTime($ticket['date']);
    $norm_date = $new_date_ticket->format('d.m.Y');
    if ((int)$ticket['status'] == Tickets::STATUS_ON) {
        $allowTickets[$norm_date] = [];
        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['tickets'] = (int)$ticket['tickets_left'];
        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'] = [];
        if ((int)$ticket['tickets_left'] > 0) {
            $i = 0;
            Yii::info($ticket);
            Yii::info($ticket['schedule_minute']);
            foreach ($ticket['schedule_minute'] as $time_hour) {
                Yii::info($time_hour);
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['value'] = (int)$time_hour->hour;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['label'] = (string)$time_hour->hour;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['tickets'] = $time_hour->tickets_left;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['price_children'] = $time_hour->price_children;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['price_stud'] = $time_hour->price_stud;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['price_adults'] = $time_hour->price_adults;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['minutes'] = [];
                if ((int)$time_hour->tickets_left > 0) {
                    $y = 0;
                    foreach ($time_hour['minutes'] as $time_minute) {
                        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['minutes'][$y]['value'] = (int)$time_minute->minute;
                        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['minutes'][$y]['label'] = (string)$time_minute->minute;
                        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$i]['minutes'][$y]['tickets'] = $time_minute->count_ticket_left;
                        $y++;
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вообщем нужна ваша помощь, как получить доступ к этим данным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё я нашел ошибку, всё просто, вообщем вот рабочий код:

```
foreach ($scheduleTickets as $ticket) {
    $new_date_ticket = new DateTime($ticket['date']);
    $norm_date = $new_date_ticket->format('d.m.Y');
    if ((int)$ticket['status'] == Tickets::STATUS_ON) {
        $allowTickets[$norm_date] = [];
        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['tickets'] = (int)$ticket['tickets_left'];
        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'] = [];
        if ((int)$ticket['tickets_left'] > 0) {
            $hours = json_decode($ticket['schedule_minute']);
            for ($h = 0; $h < count($hours); $h++) {
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['value'] = (int)$hours[$h]->hour;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['label'] = (string)$hours[$h]->hour;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['tickets'] = $hours[$h]->tickets_left;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['price_children'] = $hours[$h]->price_children;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['price_stud'] = $hours[$h]->price_stud;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['price_adults'] = $hours[$h]->price_adults;
                $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['minutes'] = [];
                if ((int)$hours[$h]->tickets_left > 0) {
                    $minutes = $hours[$h]->minutes;
                    for ($m = 0; $m < count($minutes); $m++) {
                        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['minutes'][$m]['value'] = (int)$minutes[$m]->minute;
                        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['minutes'][$m]['label'] = (string)$minutes[$m]->minute;
                        $allowTickets[$norm_date]['hours'][$h]['minutes'][$m]['tickets'] = $minutes[$m]->count_ticket_left;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```